# Displaying all elements of a vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, vector

#### First `for` loop

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= vec.size(); i++) {
    if (vec.size() == 0) {
      cout << "[] The list is Empty" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
  }
}
```

#### Second `for` loop

```
cout << "[ ";
for(auto num : vec)
  cout << num << " ";
cout << "]";
```

Why is it that when I display all the elements in a vector using the first `for` loop I get "0" at the end of the vector. However, when I use the range for loop, I do not get the zero.

Comment: also `vec.size()` gives you unsigned int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first loop, when `i` reaches `vec.size()`, `vec[i]` is out of bounds of `vec`, which leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). You need to change the loop condition from `i<=vec.size()` to `i<vec.size()`.

Also, your check for `vec.size() == 0` inside of the loop will never be true. That check needs to be moved above the loop.

```
if (vec.size() == 0) {
    cout << "[] The list is Empty" << endl;
}
for (i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
    cout <<vec[i] << " ";
}
```

On the other hand, [ranged-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates over all the elements exactly and keep us away from such troubles.